# Are questions about drug approvals on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about drug approvals on-topic?

E.g.

> Biafine is a topical non-steroidal medication, which has been used use in France for over 25 years. Why did the U.S. Food and Drug Administration approve Biafine for prescription only in 2006?